# What's a good translation of "きれいごと"?

Tags: words

Like in the examples:

「自分が不幸でも他の人が幸せならいいなんて綺麗事だよ」

「人は外見より中身だ、なんて綺麗事だよ」

In the dictionary I found `lip service`, but it doesn't "feel" very natural to me, although maybe that's just my impression.

What are some other words/expressions which I use in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hollow/empty words** (n.) or **ring hollow** (v.), **sound empty/hollow** fits the meaning of 綺麗事, as it explicitly dismisses the subject-matter as unrealistic and reflects the hypocrisy connotation of 綺麗事. However, it fails to reflect the connotation of how the subject-matter sounds great at first glance.

In this case, **idealistic** (adj.) can be used instead, to reflect both the superficial positive quality and the unreality of the subject-matter.

> 「自分が不幸でも他の人が幸せならいいなんて綺麗事だよ」
>
> It's idealistic to put the happiness of other people before your own.
>
> Putting the happiness of other people before your own - how idealistic that is.

> 「人は外見より中身だ、なんて綺麗事だよ」
>
> It's idealistic to expect people to value personality over looks
>
> Personality over looks - how idealistic that is.

Comment: +1 This answer has the better translations of the word きれいごと unlike definitions in old (open and aboveboard) and modern (whitewashing) dictionaries I have.

Answer (score 2):

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q108124570
>
> - That's so fake! (ウソっぽいという意味）
> - That's [a] very superficial statement.   (現実的でないこと）
> - nice words や fine words で良いのではないでしょうか。

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8c%e3%81%84%e4%ba%8b
--> 6件 (other than [nice words]  and  [fine words ],  not too helpful)

The 1st word that came to my mind was platitude(s).

From Obama's speech (?) -- Probably no political platitude is more invoked or more ignored than this: let's do it for the kids.

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/platitude ---
>   Beauty, I suppose, opens the heart, extends the consciousness. It is a platitude, of course.
>
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bromide  ---
>   We hoped the speech would include reassurances, but instead it was merely one bromide after another.

"feel-good bromides create the illusion of problem solving"

truism, cliche,

Sherlock Holmes may have called it a "commonplace".